# Undefined variable in foreach statement PHP

Tags: php, arrays

This has confused me, i am tiring to store an array as a variable before posting the variable into my database.

here is my code

```
foreach( $_POST['parts'] as $key => $value){
        $aparts .= $value.',';

    }
```

it stores `$aparts` fine but i get the Undefined variable error in the following line.

```
$aparts .= $value.',';
```

I am quite new and learning as i go I would like to know why this has happened :)

Comment: Define it before: `$aparts = '';`.

Comment: "*I know the easiest method would to turn off error reporting*", no - the easiest method would be to fix it, by simply defining it as already suggested.

Comment: @Qirel I agree with the answers from my question i have fixed the problem and learnt something so i am very grateful i have deleted that comment from my original question

Comment: Suppressing errors and ignoring errors (even if they are just notices) are bad practice, one should always write code in a way that it always handle them. Good thing you managed to figure it out! (Even thought this is a duplicate question, you would've found the answer [on this StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-and-notice-undefined-index)). :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It´s because you´re trying to append to `$aparts` without it being defined. To fix it define it before the foreach:

```
$aparts = "";
foreach( $_POST['parts'] as $key => $value){
   $aparts .= $value.',';
}
```

PHP has also a function called `implode()` which has the exact same result as your foreach loop:

```
$aparts = implode(",", $_POST['parts']);
```

Comment: Thanks :) i have used your addition answer it is a tidier way to do this thanks for your answer

Comment: And an explode() function that will get you your array from the string once you read it. http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php - But this will cause issues if any of your 'parts' have commas.

Answer (score 3):

You could use [**serialize()**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) when inserting and [**unserialize()**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php) when reading from the database. This will take an array and create a string for you that you can save. Then, unserialize takes that string and creates the array again.

**This will work even if your content has commas in it.** Your current method (and the other answer) will not, it will separate a single string with a comma into two separate entries in your final array.

Answer (score 1):

You should declare `$aparts`before the `foreach` statement:

```
$aparts = '';
foreach ($_POST['parts'] as $key => $value) { //...
```